# MariaDB Encryption at Rest via AWS KMS Plugin - Key Rotation Not Working?

Tags: mysql, encryption, mariadb, amazon-kms, key-management

I have set up [MariaDB for encryption at rest](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/data-at-rest-encryption/) via the [AWS Key Management Service (KMS) Plugin](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/aws-key-management-encryption-plugin/).

Everything seems to work except for the key cycling.

I have configured the below options as per the attached config files:

> /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
# InnoDB/XtraDB Encryption
innodb_encrypt_tables = On
innodb_encrypt_log = On
innodb_encryption_threads = 8
innodb_encryption_rotate_key_age = 1
innodb_encryption_rotation_iops = 100
```

> /etc/my.cnf.d/aws_key_management.cnf

```
[mariadb]

# Load the AWs plugin and enable it for use
plugin-load-add=aws_key_management.so

# Link to the AWS KMS 'Customer Master Key' used to decrypt MariaDB 
encryption keys on disk
# during MariaDB start up and save the decrypted keys into memory
aws_key_management_master_key_id = alias/MariaDB-Encryption-Key

# Specify the AWS region our KMS key is stored in
aws_key_management_region = eu-west-2

# Specify the key specification
aws_key_management_key_spec = AES_256

# Rotate all keys
aws_key_management_rotate_key = -1

# Change the plugins log level
# Options: "Off" (default), "Fatal", "Error", "Warn", "Info", 
"Debug", and "Trace".
aws_key_management_log_level = Warn

!include /etc/my.cnf.d/enable_encryption.preset
```

As you can see, I have set all keys to rotate using `aws_key_management_rotate_key = -1` and set a key age of 1 using `innodb_encryption_rotate_key_age = 1`, yet I can see from the keys in `/var/lib/mysql/` that version 1 of the keys is still being used despite these settings having been in place for multiple days:

```
/var/lib/mysql/aws-kms-key.1.1
/var/lib/mysql/aws-kms-key.2.1
```

(**Note**: the final .n suffix on the file name represents the key version)

The only thing I can think of, is that my understanding of `innodb_encryption_rotate_key_age` being measured in days in incorrect? The documentation for this option can be seen below, and makes no reference at all to what unit of measurement is used with this numeric value?

> **[innodb_encryption_rotate_key_age](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/xtradbinnodb-server-system-variables/#innodb_encryption_rotate_key_age)**
>
> **Description**: Re-encrypt in background any page having a key older than >this. When setting up Encryption, this variable must be set to a non-zero >value. Otherwise, when you enable encryption through innodb_encrypt_tables >MariaDB won't be able to automatically encrypt any unencrypted tables.

Can anyone explain why this would be and why my keys are not rotating?

**MariaDB Version**

```
mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.2.15-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1`
```

**AWS KMS Plugin Version**

```
yum list installed | grep mariadb
MariaDB-aws-key-management.x86_64       10.2.15-1.el7.centos     @mariadb-main
```

Answer (score 0):

## The basic rotation

As a workaround, you can trigger the rotation via the global variable. MariaDB and/or the plugin seem to take no action based on the config value, as you've described. The upside of this, is that you don't have to restart the database.

1. Don't forget to remove `aws_key_management_rotate_key` from the config, because you won't need it.
2. Trigger the rotation by setting the global value from the console. Note that you don't need to reset it 0 manually after the rotation. The plugin will report generating a new set (versions) of datakeys.

```sql
MariaDB [(none)]> SET @@GLOBAL.aws_key_management_rotate_key=-1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 4 warnings (0.875 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT @@GLOBAL.aws_key_management_rotate_key;
+----------------------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.aws_key_management_rotate_key |
+----------------------------------------+
|                                      0 |
+----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW WARNINGS;
+-------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level | Code | Message                                                             |
+-------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Note  | 1105 | AWS KMS plugin: generated encrypted datakey for key id=1, version=2 |
| Note  | 1105 | AWS KMS plugin: loaded key 1, version 2, key length 256 bit         |
| Note  | 1105 | AWS KMS plugin: generated encrypted datakey for key id=2, version=2 |
| Note  | 1105 | AWS KMS plugin: loaded key 2, version 2, key length 256 bit         |
+-------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.000 sec)
```

Reference: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/aws-key-management-encryption-plugin/#rotating-keys

## Gotcha #1: allowed version aging

Unfortunately, this is not over. Version 2 will now be used to encrypt new pages by default, however the pages encrypted with the previous version will not be re-encrypted in the background, as one would expect. This is due to the setting `innodb_encryption_rotate_key_age=0` *disabling* background encryption, as opposed to forcing `0` key-version age. So, the minimum age gap that we can set is `1`, which allows the use of the previous version (Version 1 in my case) for encryption by the db.

3. Check the innodb tablespace encryption. MIN_KEY_VERSION means:

   > Minimum key version used to encrypt a page in the tablespace. Different pages may be encrypted with different key versions.

```
MariaDB [test]> SELECT NAME, MIN_KEY_VERSION, CURRENT_KEY_VERSION, ROTATING_OR_FLUSHING FROM information_schema.INNODB_TABLESPACES_ENCRYPTION;
+----------------------------+-----------------+---------------------+----------------------+
| NAME                       | MIN_KEY_VERSION | CURRENT_KEY_VERSION | ROTATING_OR_FLUSHING |
+----------------------------+-----------------+---------------------+----------------------+
| innodb_system              |               1 |                   2 |                    0 |
| mysql/gtid_slave_pos       |               1 |                   2 |                    0 |
| mysql/innodb_index_stats   |               1 |                   2 |                    0 |
| mysql/innodb_table_stats   |               1 |                   2 |                    0 |
| mysql/transaction_registry |               1 |                   2 |                    0 |
| test/tbl                   |               1 |                   2 |                    0 |
+----------------------------+-----------------+---------------------+----------------------+
6 rows in set (0.000 sec)
```

4. Repeat the rotation from step 2 once more, to have MIN_KEY_VERSION at least `2`. That will also mean, that you will need to keep both version 2 and version 3 of the keys around.

Reference: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/information-schema-innodb_tablespaces_encryption-table/

## Gotcha #2: redo log

The redo log is still encrypted with the previous key version, and MariaDB won't start if the old key is missing.

```
 0 [ERROR] mysqld: can't open file aws-kms-key.1.1
 0 [Warning] mysqld: AWS KMS plugin: key 1, version 1 could not be decrypted
 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Obtaining redo log encryption key version 1 failed (2385237688). Maybe the key or the required encryption key management plugin was not found.
...
 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: No valid checkpoint found (corrupted redo log). You can try --innodb-force-recovery=6 as a last resort.
...
 0 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

> Key rotation for the InnoDB redo log is only supported in MariaDB 10.4.0 and later. See MDEV-12041 about that.

Reference: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/encrypting-data-for-innodb-xtradb/#key-rotation